# Loop Filter data and copy it with header to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have data(Account numbers) in column D that I need to Loop filter this data, copy and paste filtered data into a new sheet.

I want to copy the filtered data **with the header**, also I want to copy all filtered data to **1 sheet**, that new filtered data with its header goes under the last row and so on.

N.B: My columns go from A to Z

How can I do that using VBA?

[image]

i tied the below code but it copies each filtered range to a new sheet, i want all copied data in 1 sheet under each other

```
Sub CopyFilteredDataToNewSheets()
      Dim r As Integer, Account As String
      With Worksheets("Sheet1")
          .Range("A1:Z1").AutoFilter
          For r = 2 To 24
              Account = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & r).Value
              On Error Resume Next
              If Sheets(Account) Is Nothing Then
                  .Range("A1:Z1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Account
                  .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                  Sheets.Add.Name = Account
                  Sheets(Account).Paste
                  .ShowAllData
              End If
          Next r
      End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: If you google "how to loop through a range with VBA" you'd probably find something useful. Additionally there are probably hundreds of examples of vba loops/answers on this site. Probably a good place to start.

Comment: @pgSystemTester hey, I already tried, my only problem is I can't copy the filtered data to one sheet, it copies each range of filtered data to a new sheet, is there any way i can copy my data to one sheet under each other with header ?

Comment: Please show us the VBA code that you've tried and how it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Filtered Ranges One Below the Other

**Sheet1 (Before)**

[image]

**Sheet2 (After)**

[image]

**The Code**

```vb
Sub CreateSummary()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const SOURCE_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const SOURCE_FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 4
    ' Destination
    Const DESTINATION_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const DESTINATION_GAP As Long = 1 ' empty rows in-between

    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg').
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(SOURCE_NAME)
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Range(SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS).CurrentRegion
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount = 1 Then Exit Sub ' only headers or empty worksheet
    
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    If scCount < SOURCE_FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    
    ' Write the values from the filter column ('srfg') to an array ('sData').
    
    Dim sfrg As Range: Set sfrg = srg.Columns(SOURCE_FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX)
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = sfrg.Value
    
    ' Return the unique values and their number of occurrences
    ' in a dictionary ('dict').
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sString As String
    Dim sr As Long
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        sString = CStr(sData(sr, 1))
        If Len(sString) > 0 Then dict(sString) = dict(sString) + 1 ' count
    Next sr
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values or blanks
    Erase sData
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell ('dCell').
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dsh As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(DESTINATION_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dsh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=sws)
    dws.Name = DESTINATION_NAME
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Copy column widths.
    
    srg.Rows(1).Copy
    dCell.Resize(, scCount).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    dCell.Select
    
    ' Copy the filtered ranges one below the other.
    
    Dim sKey As Variant
    
    For Each sKey In dict.Keys
        srg.AutoFilter SOURCE_FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX, sKey
        srg.Copy dCell
        sws.ShowAllData
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(DESTINATION_GAP + dict(sKey) + 1)
    Next sKey
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    'wb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    ' Inform.
        
    MsgBox "Summary created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir that was brilliant !! , I would like to ask if I have 2 criteria, I need also to filter column A which contains my company codes (it's not unique values but repetitive like UK1, UK2, and so on. I want to filter for UK1 in column A first then Filter the unique values in column D in a loop and copy data to a new sheet.

Comment: I corrected a mistake: the `If IsError...` line was redundant: once the value is converted to a string, it can never ever be an error value. Your new requirement is out of the scope of this question and you have poorly described it. Best ask another question, explain what the code does, and explain accurately and in more detail what you additionally want it to do. You can add a link to the new question in your comments (right below your post), so the contributors (me included), interested in this question, can easily find it (since they are following it).

Comment: Noted Sir, Thanks for your efforts.