# Loop Filter data based on 2 criterial and copy it with header to new sheets

Tags: excel, vba

So Reference to My old question here that was solved by @VBasic2008, it worked quite well.

[Loop Filter data and copy it with header to a new sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989389/loop-filter-data-and-copy-it-with-header-to-a-new-sheet)

Now I wonder if I can tweak this code to filter **two criteria instead of 1**, as I need to filter column A also which contains my company codes (it's not unique values but repetitive like UK1, UK2, and so on. I want to filter for UK1 in column A first then Filter the unique values in column D in a loop and copy data to a new sheet.

with the code mentioned below or in the link shared, it filters only the unique values in column D and copies it to a new sheet.
I need to filter columns A and Column D as per the below screenshot. My columns that contain the data go from A to Z

[image]

Code:

```
Sub CreateSummary()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const SOURCE_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const SOURCE_FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 4
    ' Destination
    Const DESTINATION_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const DESTINATION_GAP As Long = 1 ' empty rows in-between

    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg').
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(SOURCE_NAME)
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Range(SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS).CurrentRegion
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount = 1 Then Exit Sub ' only headers or empty worksheet
    
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    If scCount < SOURCE_FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    
    ' Write the values from the filter column ('srfg') to an array ('sData').
    
    Dim sfrg As Range: Set sfrg = srg.Columns(SOURCE_FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX)
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = sfrg.Value
    
    ' Return the unique values and their number of occurrences
    ' in a dictionary ('dict').
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sString As String
    Dim sr As Long
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        sString = CStr(sData(sr, 1))
        If Len(sString) > 0 Then dict(sString) = dict(sString) + 1 ' count
    Next sr
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values or blanks
    Erase sData
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell ('dCell').
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dsh As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(DESTINATION_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dsh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=sws)
    dws.Name = DESTINATION_NAME
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Copy column widths.
    
    srg.Rows(1).Copy
    dCell.Resize(, scCount).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    dCell.Select
    
    ' Copy the filtered ranges one below the other.
    
    Dim sKey As Variant
    
    For Each sKey In dict.Keys
        srg.AutoFilter SOURCE_FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX, sKey
        srg.Copy dCell
        sws.ShowAllData
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(DESTINATION_GAP + dict(sKey) + 1)
    Next sKey
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    'wb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    ' Inform.
        
    MsgBox "Summary created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: How to proceed the code in case of no any line (except the header) will be the result of both filters? Should it copy only the header and (eventually) after the last column to writhe the concatenation between values in "A" and "D" (the filters elements)? Or skip the copying for such cases?

Comment: @FaneDuru that's another problem I am facing, it copies empty headers and rows.

Comment: Empty headers, I can understand, but which rows, if there is no one? I already prepared an answer, writing the concatenation between company code and filter criteria in D:D, separated by underscore ("_"), after the last header column. I will post it in one minute. If you need to skip that cases of no filtered rows, I can adapt the code after that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next updated code. It uses other two dictionaries (one for unique company codes and another one to keep the occurrences for each combination Company code - Filter criteria:

```
Sub CreateSummaryTwoFilters()
    Const SOURCE_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const FILTER_COLUMN1_INDEX As Long = 1
    Const FILTER_COLUMN2_INDEX As Long = 4
    ' Destination
    Const DESTINATION_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const DESTINATION_GAP As Long = 1 ' empty rows in-between

    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(SOURCE_NAME)
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Range(SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS).CurrentRegion
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.rows.count
    If srCount = 1 Then Exit Sub ' only headers or empty worksheet
    
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.count
    If scCount < FILTER_COLUMN2_INDEX Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    
    'place all the range in an array for faster iteration:
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Return the unique values of cells in A:A and D:D and the number of occurrences for each concatenated pair:
    Dim dictA As Object: Set dictA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictA.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim dictD As Object: Set dictD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictD.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim dictAD As Object: Set dictAD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictAD.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sString As String, sr As Long
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        sString = CStr(sData(sr, FILTER_COLUMN2_INDEX))
        If Len(sData(sr, 1)) > 0 Then dictA(sData(sr, 1)) = vbNullString
        If Len(sString) > 0 Then dictD(sString) = vbNullString
        dictAD(sData(sr, 1) & "_" & sData(sr, 4)) = dictAD(sData(sr, 1) & "_" & sData(sr, 4)) + 1 'count rows of both occurrence on the same row
    Next sr
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Sheets(DESTINATION_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not dws Is Nothing Then
            dws.cells.ClearContents
    Else
            Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=sws)
            dws.name = DESTINATION_NAME
    End If
    
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Copy column widths.
    srg.rows(1).Copy ' copy the headers columns width
    dCell.Resize(, scCount).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    
    ' Copy the filtered ranges one after the other.
    Dim sKeyA As Variant, sKeyD As Variant
    
    For Each sKeyA In dictA.Keys       'iterate between each key of company codes dictionary
        For Each sKeyD In dictD.Keys   'Iterate between each key of D:D criteria dictionary
            srg.AutoFilter FILTER_COLUMN1_INDEX, sKeyA 'place the filters:
            srg.AutoFilter FILTER_COLUMN2_INDEX, sKeyD
            srg.Copy dCell             'copy the filtered range
            'if no any filter row resulted, writhe the keys combination on the headers row (after the last column):
            If dictAD(sKeyA & "_" & sKeyD) = "" Then dCell.Offset(, scCount).Value = sKeyA & "_" & sKeyD
            sws.ShowAllData:
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(DESTINATION_GAP + dictAD(sKeyA & "_" & sKeyD) + 1) 'reinitialize the cell where to paste next time
        Next sKeyD
    Next sKeyA
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    'wb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    ' Inform.
     dws.Activate
    MsgBox "Summary created.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version, which should do what (I understood) you need. I had some problems with the fact that the code used to stop after inserting a worksheet... I added code lines to stop events, calculation etc.:

```
Sub CreateSummaryTwoFiltersPerCompCode()
    Const SOURCE_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const FILTER_COLUMN1_INDEX As Long = 1
    Const FILTER_COLUMN2_INDEX As Long = 4
    ' Destination
    Const DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const DESTINATION_GAP As Long = 1 ' empty rows in-between

    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(SOURCE_NAME)
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Range(SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS).CurrentRegion
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.rows.count
    If srCount = 1 Then Exit Sub ' only headers or empty worksheet
    
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.count
    If scCount < FILTER_COLUMN2_INDEX Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    
    'place all the range in an array for faster iteration:
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Return the unique values of cells in A:A and D:D and the number of occurrences for each concatenated pair:
    Dim dictA As Object: Set dictA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictA.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim dictD As Object: Set dictD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictD.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim dictAD As Object: Set dictAD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictAD.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sString As String, sr As Long
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        sString = CStr(sData(sr, FILTER_COLUMN2_INDEX))
        If Len(sData(sr, 1)) > 0 Then dictA(sData(sr, 1)) = vbNullString
        If Len(sString) > 0 Then dictD(sString) = vbNullString
        dictAD(sData(sr, 1) & "_" & sData(sr, 4)) = dictAD(sData(sr, 1) & "_" & sData(sr, 4)) + 1 'count rows of both occurrence on the same row
    Next sr
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Copy the filtered ranges one after the other.
    Dim sKeyA As Variant, sKeyD As Variant, dws As Object, dCell As Range
    For Each sKeyA In dictA.Keys       'iterate between each key of company codes dictionary
       'insert a new sheet per company code:
       Set dws = Nothing
       On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Sheets(sKeyA)
       On Error GoTo 0

       If Not dws Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
              dws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
        'a lot of measures to avoid stopping the code after the sheet insertion...
        Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
             Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=sws)
             dws.name = sKeyA
             DoEvents
        Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
        Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        
        Set dCell = dws.Range(DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        ' Copy column widths.
        srg.rows(1).Copy ' copy the headers columns width
        dCell.Resize(, scCount).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    
        For Each sKeyD In dictD.Keys   'Iterate between each key of D:D criteria dictionary
            srg.AutoFilter FILTER_COLUMN1_INDEX, sKeyA 'place the filters:
            srg.AutoFilter FILTER_COLUMN2_INDEX, sKeyD
                                      
            If dictAD(sKeyA & "_" & sKeyD) <> "" Then
                srg.Copy dCell    'copy the filtered range
                sws.ShowAllData
                Set dCell = dCell.Offset(DESTINATION_GAP + dictAD(sKeyA & "_" & sKeyD) + 1) 'reinitialize the cell where to paste next time
            End If
        Next sKeyD
    Next sKeyA
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    'wb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    ' Inform.
     dws.Activate
    MsgBox "Summary created.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey FaneDuru, the code returns a blank Sheet2. I've added screenshots from the columns i want to filter in the body of the post, i really appreciate your time helping me.

Comment: @Martin The code uses the existing `DESTINATION_NAME` if already created. It only clear its content. Did the code that? Please, try running it again and observe this aspect. In fact, put a break point of the line `srg.rows(1).Copy` Does the code reach it? When code is stopped on this line, was the destination sheet cleared? If so press `F5` to let the code running...

Comment: I double tested it and it worked smoothly, there are a lot of empty rows with headers copied also in the sheet though. sorry if I didn't mention this but can I copy filtered data to new sheets and the name of new sheets is based on the company code which is in column A ?

Comment: @Martin I am afraid I cannot get you... What do you mean by "the name of new sheets is based on the company code"? I couldn't deduce anything about such a way having the name placed in a `Constant`... I understood that the company code(s) are in column A:A. Do you want copying all of them in a sheet with the name of one company name? Or you try saying that for each company name a new sheet must be inserted and copy in it only the filtered range with that company name as the first filter criteria? Like I said, the above version copies the header and a concatenated marker after the last column.

Comment: so basically this report is about vendor numbers for each company code, so vendor numbers are in column D and company codes in Column A. I wonder if i can copy all vendor numbers in column D that is related to UK1 and paste them in a new sheet called UK1 then do the same for UK2 and so on.

Comment: @Martin I thought that you maybe need/want to know for which criteria in D:D there are no filtered rows...

Comment: @Martin If you better explain what what you mean by that, it should be possible. But I understood from your question that company codes are in A:A ("UK1, UK2")? Did I wrongly understood your question? If not, as I asked before, do you want inserting a new sheet for each such a company code, naming the inserted sheet as company code and place there only the filtered ranges for that specific one? And, besides that, do you want skipping the cases of no any filtered row, except the headers?

Comment: Yes sir, i just want to filter data in column D (vendor numbers) based on data in column A (Company codes) and copy the filtered data to a new sheet named after the company code, so I would have 5 sheets (as I have 5 company codes) with all their vendor numbers. and escaping the empty rows would be great!

Comment: @Martin So, do you confirm that inserting a new sheet for **each unique company code from A:A**, name it as that specific company code and place there only filtered ranges of the respective one, filtered by all D:D criteria is a good understanding of what you need? I could not understand this from your question... What about running the code for second time? should the code delete the previous inserted sheets, as it used to do in your original code (without the second filtering criteria)?

Comment: Exactly what I need sir! I don't get the last part of the code deleting previously inserted sheets, i don't want to delete anything as i will use the code for one-time use and not a recurring event.

Comment: @Martin OK, but if you run it for the second time, by mistake, or after some modifications it should be able to deal with that... I will try design it it to delete the existing sheets, if the case and inserting new ones ANYHOW...

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Sir!! really appreciate your support.

Comment: @Martin Please, test the version I posted after **Edited**. I designed it in less than 5 minutes, but the code used to stop after inserting and processing the first sheet. I placed some code lines to avoid that, I do not know now if all of them are necessary but no time to exclude one by one and check...

Comment: It WORKED Flawlessly !!! Thanks Fane!